How to indent sql inside transactions with sqlfluff
I'm using sqlfluff 3.1.0 with the postgres dialect.
I'd like to be able to indent transactions like this:
BEGIN;

    some_indented_sql;

COMMIT;

However sqlfluff, by default anyway, insists on left justifying the inside of the transaction with the BEGIN/COMMIT keywords like this:
BEGIN;

some_not_indented_sql;

COMMIT;

Is there a way to get it to indent the way I'd prefer?

this may help you ... https://docs.sqlfluff.com/en/stable/layout.html#layoutconfig

thanks.  unfortunately there doesn't appear to be an option to indent transactions documented there, just joins.
